# Oracle - Constraint to allow only specific characters

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I want to make a constraint on a column so i can only insert the letters M, F or T.
I tried to make one with REGEXP_LIKE but i get errors.

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLE_NAME] ADD CONSTRAINT 
[CONSTR_NAME] CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (COL, '^[M-M,F-F,T-T])\w+'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as:

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLE_NAME] ADD CONSTRAINT [CONSTR_NAME]  
    CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(COL, '^[MFT]*$'));
```

That is, the column has any of the letters M, F, or T occurring any number of times.  These are the only characters allowed from the beginning of the string (`^`) to the end (`$`).

Note:  An empty string does not match this pattern because it is equivalent to `NULL` (by default) in Oracle.

I should also note that your question is a little ambiguous.  If the value can only be one of M, F, or T, then use `IN`:

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLE_NAME] ADD CONSTRAINT [CONSTR_NAME]  
    CHECK (COL IN ('M', 'F', 'T') );
```